# Trying to understand what (if any) performance boost I can expect from an async/await pattern in this case

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I have a JS function using Ajax that generally hits the server every 3 seconds in order to update several elements on the page.

The JS call is something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: './Updater/GetJsonRes',
    data: {},
    success: function (response) {
        clientinfo = response;
        processUpdate();
    }
});
```

The code-behind function returns a `JsonResult`, using 
`return Json(clients, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

what I'm wondering is if I stand to gain any performance increase with the following async pattern:

Instead of calling the function directly that returns the JsonResult, I've setup a function as follows:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> GetJsonRes() {
  return await Task.Run(() => getClientsInfo());
}
```

The function `getClientsInfo()` is defined simply as `public JsonResult getClientsInfo()`

I guess I'm also wondering if this pattern is correct to begin with. If say 10 people had the page open, that function would be getting called approximately every 3 seconds, by each page that is up.

Would calling `getClientsInfo()` in this pattern be fully non-blocking?

I guess I should also ask, if this is wrong/ineffective, what would be a more effective pattern?

Edit:

Just from a purely observational standpoint, I changed the update rate to 100 ms from 3 seconds, and opened a bunch of pages. I noticed with the Ajax call going straight to `getClientsInfo`, there was some struggling going on to update all the pages that quickly.

While calling the async function with the 100 ms delay, all the browser windows appeared to be updated with ease.

Comment: Use AJAX only for big and havy requests, to load big parts of pages, images, etc. For update several elements on the page is better to use something like `long-polling` or `COMET`. Google it, maybe it is what you are looking for.

Comment: I may look into SignalR at some point but for the scope of this project a simple Ajax call is perfectly suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of each thread just handling any given response, you're now asking it to instead do nothing but schedule the work to be done by another thread, wait for another thread to go and pick it up, have *that* thread go do the work, then send it back to another thread to complete the original request.

So you're adding a bunch of scheduling overhead, and gaining nothing in exchange.  It will only ever hurt performance.

Comment: This is what I suspected but also now confused as to why the pages are behaving more normally with the call to the async function? A 100ms update time is unreasonable in any case, but the performance seems _much_ better with the call to the async function

Comment: And as far as the additional questions in my original post, is there an async/await pattern in this instance that I would benefit from?

Comment: @Yelnik If you have an actually asynchronous operations, then sure.  If not, then no.

Comment: When you say "instead of each thread just handling any given response", are you implying that every time this function is requested, .NET would spawn a 'thread' for each functional call? What if the function is called 10 times at the same instant? Are they processed successively or concurrently? If the current async pattern I'm doing really does spawn a new thread for each call, is this not more concurrent than the non-async pattern? Sorry but I'm not gathering the original information I was asking for so far

Comment: @Yelnik It's not creating a new thread, it's adding work to the thread pool for one of the pooled threads to work on.  Giving a new worker the job of doing nothing but creating new work for another worker is not increasing the amount of parallelism.  It's just giving a thread some pointless work to do, when it could have just done the requested work in the first place.

Comment: Having said that, is there any way to justify the increase in performance with a useless async call? And is there something I could roughly reference for what the right pattern would be?

Comment: @Yelnik You haven't described anything about what the measured performance differences are, how you did the benchmarks, what the actual work is, etc., so no, I couldn't possibly comment on why your results differ.  As for the right pattern, if you consider not performing entirely superfluous operation a pattern, then I guess follow that.